# Android: QuickBox chatService.login failure

Tags: android, messaging, instant

I am trying to use QuickBox to establish IM in my application, testing it in a new project, but it seems the login onSuccess and onError are never triggered. The session is created but the login is failing (but without any error returned), both toasts in onSuccess and onError are never reached.

```
QBSettings.getInstance().init(getApplicationContext(), APP_ID, AUTH_KEY, AUTH_SECRET);
    QBSettings.getInstance().setAccountKey(ACCOUNT_KEY);
    try {
        QBAuth.getBaseService().setToken("bede1c97d992755ba5ceae43b76ded687c71a1c2");
    } catch (BaseServiceException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    QBChatService.setDebugEnabled(true); 
    QBChatService.setDefaultConnectionTimeout(60);
    final QBChatService chatService = QBChatService.getInstance();
    final QBUser user = new QBUser("roudy", "kanaan123");
    QBAuth.createSession(user, new QBEntityCallback<QBSession>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(final QBSession session, Bundle params) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Session Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            user.setId(1);
            chatService.login(user, new QBEntityCallback() { // also tried QBChatService.getInstance().login

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Object o, Bundle bundle) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "user logged in", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    privateChatManager = chatService.getPrivateChatManager();
                    privateChatManager.createDialog(2, new QBEntityCallback<QBDialog>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(QBDialog dialog, Bundle args) {
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "dialog created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(QBResponseException errors) {
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), errors.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });

                    privateChatMessageListener = new QBMessageListener<QBPrivateChat>() {
                        @Override
                        public void processMessage(QBPrivateChat privateChat, final QBChatMessage chatMessage) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void processError(QBPrivateChat privateChat, QBChatException error, QBChatMessage originMessage) {

                        }
                    };

                    privateChatManagerListener = new QBPrivateChatManagerListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void chatCreated(final QBPrivateChat privateChat, final boolean createdLocally) {
                            if (!createdLocally) {
                                privateChat.addMessageListener(privateChatMessageListener);
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    QBChatService.getInstance().getPrivateChatManager().addPrivateChatManagerListener(privateChatManagerListener);

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(QBResponseException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(QBResponseException errors) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, errors.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

I can see this is in the run/android monitor log:

```
    07-28 09:21:54.107 16144-16184/com.example.roudy.quickboxtest D/QBASDK: Connecting to chat: chat.quickblox.com
07-28 09:21:54.143 16144-16167/com.example.roudy.quickboxtest W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
07-28 09:21:54.143 16144-16167/com.example.roudy.quickboxtest W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa346ec20, error=EGL_SUCCESS
07-28 09:21:54.158 16144-16167/com.example.roudy.quickboxtest V/RenderScript: 0xae9b0800 Launching thread(s), CPUs 4
07-28 09:21:54.466 16144-16198/com.example.roudy.quickboxtest D/SMACK: SENT (0): <stream:stream xmlns='jabber:client' to='chat.quickblox.com' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' version='1.0' xml:lang='en'>
07-28 09:21:54.661 16144-16199/com.example.roudy.quickboxtest D/SMACK: RECV (0): <?xml version='1.0'?><stream:stream xmlns='jabber:client' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' from='chat.quickblox.com' id='ea0fa35d-e7e1-46d9-88ea-eefab4fd8dbb' version='1.0' xml:lang='en'>
07-28 09:21:54.853 16144-16199/com.example.roudy.quickboxtest D/SMACK: RECV (0): <stream:features><sm xmlns="urn:xmpp:sm:3"/><mechanisms xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"><mechanism>PLAIN</mechanism><mechanism>ANONYMOUS</mechanism></mechanisms><ver xmlns="urn:xmpp:features:rosterver"/><starttls xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls"/><compression xmlns="http://jabber.org/features/compress"><method>zlib</method></compression></stream:features>
07-28 09:23:54.659 16144-16199/com.example.roudy.quickboxtest D/SMACK: RECV (0): </stream:stream>
07-28 09:23:54.660 16144-16198/com.example.roudy.quickboxtest D/SMACK: SENT (0): <presence id='rm2kQ-1' type='unavailable'></presence>
07-28 09:23:54.660 16144-16198/com.example.roudy.quickboxtest D/SMACK: SENT (0): </stream:stream>
```

EDIT: It seems that i'm now getting a different error in the emulator (I logged out once before the createSession and ever since am getting this):

```
07-28 09:45:28.647 5679-5735/com.example.roudy.quickboxtest D/QBASDK: Connected. Login to chat, currentUser JID: 15681103-44582, resource: android_9d191aed08b8ec31
07-28 09:45:28.648 5679-5749/com.example.roudy.quickboxtest D/SMACK: SENT (0): <auth xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl' mechanism='PLAIN'>ADE1NjgxMTAzLTQ0NTgyAGthbmFhbjEyMw==</auth>
07-28 09:45:28.835 5679-5750/com.example.roudy.quickboxtest D/SMACK: RECV (0): <failure xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"><not-authorized/></failure>
```

FIXED:

Turns out you cannot login in the Main Thread, I created a seperate class implementing Runnable and ran it in onCreate and it worked perfectly.